# Perl missing while installing nginx on centos

Tags: linux, centos, nginx, perl

I am trying to install nginx on my server, however it keeps returning "./configure: error: perl 5.6.1 or higher is required" eventhough I have perl v5.8.8!!!!

I have already downloaded perl and trying to configure it using the following command :

```
./configure --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module --with-http_flv_module --add-module=nginx_mod_h264_streaming
```

here is the output :

```
[root@fst nginx-0.8.55]# ./configure --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module --with-http_flv_module --add-module=nginx_mod_h264_streaming
checking for OS
 + Linux 2.6.18-308.el5 x86_64
checking for C compiler ... found
 + using GNU C compiler
 + gcc version: 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
checking for gcc -pipe switch ... found
checking for gcc builtin atomic operations ... found
checking for C99 variadic macros ... found
checking for gcc variadic macros ... found
checking for unistd.h ... found
checking for inttypes.h ... found
checking for limits.h ... found
checking for sys/filio.h ... not found
checking for sys/param.h ... found
checking for sys/mount.h ... found
checking for sys/statvfs.h ... found
checking for crypt.h ... found
checking for Linux specific features
checking for epoll ... found
checking for sendfile() ... found
checking for sendfile64() ... found
checking for sys/prctl.h ... found
checking for prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE) ... found
checking for sched_setaffinity() ... found
checking for crypt_r() ... found
checking for sys/vfs.h ... found
checking for nobody group ... found
checking for poll() ... found
checking for /dev/poll ... not found
checking for kqueue ... not found
checking for crypt() ... not found
checking for crypt() in libcrypt ... found
checking for F_READAHEAD ... not found
checking for posix_fadvise() ... found
checking for O_DIRECT ... found
checking for F_NOCACHE ... not found
checking for directio() ... not found
checking for statfs() ... found
checking for statvfs() ... found
checking for dlopen() ... not found
checking for dlopen() in libdl ... found
checking for sched_yield() ... found
checking for SO_SETFIB ... not found
configuring additional modules
adding module in nginx_mod_h264_streaming
 + ngx_http_h264_streaming_module was configured
checking for PCRE library ... found
checking for system md library ... not found
checking for system md5 library ... not found
checking for OpenSSL md5 crypto library ... found
checking for zlib library ... found
checking for perl
 + perl version: v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

./configure: error: perl 5.6.1 or higher is required
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you really know what you are doing I would recommend using yum to install nginx.
It is available in the EPEL repository, likely rpmforge as well.

Edit: Since you need custom modules for nginx you might be better off wrapping up your custom build into an RPM. Maintaining source builds across more than a dozen servers becomes real problematic for a small administration team.

Comment: to be honest I have used the same series of commands to install nginx on my other servers but this is the ONLY server that returns such error!!! and I need to load `--add-module=nginx_mod_h264_streaming` in to the config as its a custom made module

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing the header files for Perl. Try installing the Perl development package:

```
yum install perl-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably are just missing the development files. I've seen this happen if you don't have the following package installed

```
yum install glibc-headers
```

Comment: thats already installed!!! :S I have installed all the required libraries etc as well!!! the same set of commands worked on another server so I am guessing its a server config

Comment: did you check your config.log to see why it is erroring and not saying it is finding perl?